# Multiple inheritance of class and threading in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have an annoying problem in Python concerning the heritage of class.
The code is the following:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

class Main:

def __init__(self):
        self.var = 0
        self.fils_on()

    def fils_on(self):
        self.temp = Fils()
        self.temp.start()

    def fils_off(self):
        self.temp.stop()
        del self.temp

class Fils(Thread, Main):

    def __init__(self):
        Main.__init__(self)
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.encore = True

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while self.encore:
            chaine = str(i)
            print chaine
            print "var: ", self.var
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.encore = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
```

My problem is when I call "Main", I don't manage to print the self.var variable from Fils class.

Someone know why? 
And how can I fix it?

Comment: Your class `Main` creates a `Fils` which itself invokes the init function of `Main`. This will cause an infinite loop!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve but it seems you are trying to experiment with threads, The above implementation exceeds recursion depth because you have a cyclic dependency, `__init__` from Main class depends on `self.fils_on()` and it construct `Fils()` which trigger `Fils.__init__()` which in turn calls `Main.__init__(self)` and again the whole process continues.
Here I tried to modify your code, in which I removed the inheritance between Fils and Mains and moved var inside Fils.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

class Main:

    def __init__(self):
            self.fils_on()

    def fils_on(self):
        self.temp = Fils()
        self.temp.start()

    def fils_off(self):
        self.temp.stop()
        del self.temp

class Fils(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.encore = True
        self.var = 0


    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while self.encore:
            chaine = str(i)
            print chaine
            print "var: ", self.var
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.encore = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
```